# Name of the recipe for this type of wall?

Tags: fallout-76

What is the name of the recipe for the wall depicted in the photo below? I don't know what to call it so I can google/look myself and Fallout 76 just calls it "Wall" just like all the other walls.

[image: Fallout 76 Walls]

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be the metal wall, which is learned from the "Metal Building Set" plans: https://fallout.gamepedia.com/Plan:_Metal_Building_Set

The plans appear to be occasionally for sale from either Grahm (if you're lucky enough to find him), or the faction vendor in Watoga.

Comment: I believe the metal building set gives you a different set of walls. I have the metal building set, but I don't have these walls.

Comment: @Shelby115 Hmm, I'll have to check my character later, I was certain I had these and gained the ability to build them from the metal build set. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The metal walls seem to be the heavier-looking metal walls. I believe these are from the warehouse building set if their name in Fallout 4 matches up here, but I've spent the last couple days checking vendors and doing workshops and haven't had much luck, so I'm still not entirely certain. x.x

Answer (score 0):

**Plan:** [Warehouse Building Set](https://fallout.gamepedia.com/Plan:_Warehouse_Building_Set)

**Vendors:**

- Sold by Grafton Station and the Grafton trading post vendors
  (Responders).
- Top of the world sold by vendor in the motel.